# python code to generate password list

Tags: python

I am researching wireless security and trying to write a python script to generate passwords, not random, but a dictionary of hex numbers.  The letters need to be capital, and it has to go from 12 characters to 20 characters.  I went from 11 f's to 20 f's, this seems like it would meet the requirements.  I then tried to place them in a text file.  After I made the file, I chmod'ed it to 777 and then clicked run.  It has been a few minutes, but I cannot tell if it is working or not.  I am running it in kali right now, on a 64 bit core i3 with 8gb of ram. I'm not sure how long it would be expected to take, but this is my code, let me know if it looks right please:

```
# generate 10 to 32 character password list using hex numbers, 0-9 A-F
def gen_pwd(x):
    x = range(17592186044415 -295147905179352830000)
    def toHex(dec):
        x = (dec % 16)
        digits = "0123456789ABCDEF"
        rest = dec / 16
        if (rest == 0):
            return digits[x]
        return toHex(rest) + digits[x]

    for x in range(x):
        print toHex(x) 
    f = open(/root/Home/sdnlnk_pwd.txt)
    print f
    value = x
    string = str(value)
    f.write(string) 

gen_pwd
```

Comment: I am afraid it's not working. There are multiple syntax errors, and `gen_pwd` needs parentheses to actually call the function: `gen_pwd()`.

Comment: Also it should be `open("/root/Home/sdnlnk_pwd.txt")` (with parethesis).

Comment: I dont think that range is doing what you would expect... it will basically never pass that point ... (on the first line)

Comment: Your program will crush, by a memory error probably. That range is too big

Comment: the range is infinite ... python supports arbitrarily large  numbers it will never wrap to `17592186044415 -295147905179352830000`

Comment: Also instead of printing them, if you sure your method is correct, dont print. Also do the file process _with open("filenamedirectory/filename","a") as f: f.write(what you want to write to the file)_ . I was working on password generators before. I can give you some tips im on phone now , i will write an answer later

Comment: Another important thing, file size will be +1gb if you try to finish it. I was trying to write some inf about prime numbers, after 2min process txt.file size was like 500mb. So, this process will not be ended what you expect.. i have i7 3.8ghz and lagged when i tried to open the txt file(of course program didnt finish because of memory error)

Answer (score 2):

how bout just

```
password = hex(random.randint(1000000,100000000))[2:]
```

or

```
pw_len = 12
my_alphabet = "1234567890ABCDEF"
password = "".join(random.choice(my_alphabet) for _ in range(pw_len))
```

or what maybe closer to what you are trying to do

```
struct.pack("Q",12365468987654).encode("hex").upper()
```

basically you are overcomplicating a very simple task

to do exactly what you are asking you can simplify it

```
import itertools, struct

def int_to_chars(d):
    '''
    step 1: break into bytes
    '''
    while d > 0: # while we have not consumed
       yield struct.pack("B",d&0xFF) # decode char
       d>>=8 # shift right one byte
    yield "" # a terminator just in case its empty

def to_password(d):
    # this will convert an arbitrarily large number to a password
    return "".join(int_to_chars(d)).encode("hex").upper()  
    # you could probably just get away with `return hex(d)[2:]`

def all_the_passwords(minimum,maximum):
    #: since our numbers are so big we need to resort to some trickery
    all_pw = itertools.takewhile(lambda x:x<maximum,
                                 itertools.count(minimum))
    for pw in all_pw:
        yield to_password(pw)

all_passwords = all_the_passwords( 0xfffffffffff ,0xffffffffffffffffffff)
#this next bit is gonna take a while ... go get some coffee or something
for pw in all_passwords:
    print pw
#you will be waiting for it to finish for a very long time ... but it will get there
```

Comment: will it finish before the Earth is swallowed by the Sun? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `time.time()` to get the execution time. and if you are using python 2 use `xrange()` instead `range` because `xrange` return an iterator  :

```
import time

def gen_pwd(x):

    def toHex(dec):
        x = (dec % 16)
        digits = "0123456789ABCDEF"
        rest = dec / 16
        if (rest == 0):
            return digits[x]
        return toHex(rest) + digits[x]

    for x in range(x):
        print toHex(x) 
    f = open("/root/Home/sdnlnk_pwd.txt")
    print f
    value = x
    string = str(value)
    f.write(string) 

start= time.time()
gen_pwd()
last=time.time()-start
print last
```

Note : you need `()` to call your function and `""` in your `open()` function. also i think your first range is an extra command , as its wrong , you need to remove it.

Comment: @JoranBeasley yep , i think its extra code .

Answer (score 1):

#### Disclaimer

I'd like to comment on the OP question but I need to show some code and also the output that said code produces, so that I eventually decided to present my comment in the format of an answer.

OTOH, I hope that this comment persuades the OP that her/his undertaking, while conceptually simple (see my previous answer, 6 lines of Python code), is not feasible with available resources (I mean, available on Planet Earth).

---

### Code

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
pg = lambda n: locale.format("%d", n, grouping=True)


def count_bytes(low, hi):
    count = low+1
    for i in range(low+1,hi+1):
        nn = 15*16**(i-1)
        nc = i+1
        count = count + nn*nc
    return count

n_b = count_bytes(10,20)
n_d = n_b/4/10**12
dollars = 139.99*n_d

print "Total number of bytes to write on disk:",   pg(n_b)
print """
Considering the use of
    WD Green WD40EZRX 4TB IntelliPower 64MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5\" Internal Hard Drives,
    that you can shop at $139.99 each
   (see <http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822236604>,
    retrieved on December 29th, 2014)."""
print "\nNumber of 4TB hard disk drives necessary:", pg(n_d)
print "\nCost of said hard disks: $" + pg(dollars)
```

---

### Output

```
Total number of bytes to write on disk: 25,306,847,157,254,216,063,385,611

Considering the use of
    WD Green WD40EZRX 4TB IntelliPower 64MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drives,
    that you can shop at $139.99 each
   (see <http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822236604>,
    retrieved on December 29th, 2014).

Number of 4TB hard disk drives necessary: 6,326,711,789,313

Cost of said hard disks: $885,676,383,385,926
```

---

### My comment on what the OP wants to do

Quite a bit of disk storage (and money) is needed to accomplish your undertaking.

#### Perspective

[Projected US Federal debt at the end of fiscal year 2014 is $18.23 trillion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_United_States_federal_budget), my estimated cost, not considering racks, power supplies and energy bills, is $886 trillion.

#### Recommended reading

[Combinatorial_Explosion@SussexUniversity](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PKDq9TrjTC8J:cswww.essex.ac.uk/research/CSP/ComputationalFinanceTeaching/CombinatorialExplosion.html+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk),

#### There is hope

If you are still convinced to pursue your research project on wireless security in the direction you've described, it is possible that you can get a substantial volume discount on the drives'purchase.

Comment: i wouldn't think of it as taking such a huge volume of space, even if it puts the output of one number per line, it is counting almost 4.3 billion numbers, giving me around 80 milion pages in a word document ad the default settings, unless i am missing something.  i have figured out i need to count in hex starting at 0xfffffffffff and incrementing by 1 until i get to 0xffffffffffffffffffff.  then i convert the number to a string so i can write it and increment it.  see my new post for the code i am trying to make work.

Comment: NO. You're not going to write 4.3 billion numbers, you're going to write 19 million of billions of billions of numbers, most of them represented by 20 characters... You need over 6000 billion LARGE hard drives to store them (Earth's population is 6 billion people; the drives needed are 6000 billion). Have you read the page I linked? Last but not least, what do you want to do with that data? (It's a rethorical question, please don't bother to answer).  That said, good luck and good bye.

Comment: since you asked, i am going to use this dictionalry to crack the passwords of suddenlink routers.  there is a hint to that in the output file in the code.  as i said, i am researching this.  rather than simply trying to access the router in real time by making the numbers up as it goes, i thought it would be a little more stealthy to grab the hash from traffic interception and use a gpu to crack it offline with a dictionary.  it seems that it would be to large however, so i have since edited the code to reduce the number of passwords.  i am also questioning your math, it is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

### Preamble

I don't want to comment on what you want to do.

### Code MkI

Your code can be trimmed (quite a bit) to the following

```
with open("myfile", "w") as f:
    for x in xrange(0xff,0xff*2+1): f.write("%X\n"%x)
```

#### Comments on my code

Please note that

1. You can write hex numbers in source code as, ehm, hex numbers and you can mix hex and decimal notation as well
2. The `to_hex` function is redundant as `python` has (surprise!) a number of different ways to format your output as you please (here I've used so called [string interpolation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)).

Of course you have to change the filename in the `open` statement and
adjust the extremes of the interval generated by `xrange` (it seems
you're using `python 2.x`) to your content.

### Code MkII

Joran Beasley remarked that  (at least in Python 2.7) `xrange` internally uses a C `long` and as such it cannot  step up to the task of representing
`0XFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. This alternative code may be a possibility:

```
f = open("myfile", "w")
cursor = 0XFFFFFFFFFF
end = 0XFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
while cursor <= end:
    f.write("%X\n"%cursor)
    cursor += 1
```

Comment: xrange breaks for numbers as big as he is talking about (at least in 2.7) it tries to convert to c long ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thank you for the heads up, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
characters=["a","b","c"]
for x,y in zip(range(5),characters):
    print (hex(x)+y)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
0x0a
0x1b
0x2c
>>>
```

You see, its actually doing that with a short way. It is not possible if you use a range like that, keep it small and try to add another things to your result.

> Also for file process, here is a better way:

```
with open("filepath/name","a+") as f:
    f.write("whateveryouwanttowrite")
```

I was working with password generators, well better if you define a dict with complicated characters and compile them like:

```
passw={"h":"_*2ac","e":"=.kq","y":"%.hq1"}
x=input("Wanna make some passwords? Enter a sentence or word: ")
for i in x:
    print (passw[i],end="")
    with open("passwords.txt","a+") as f:
        f.write(passw[i])
```

Output:

```
>>> 
Wanna make some passwords? Enter a sentence or word: hey
_*2ac=.kq%.hq1
>>>
```

So, just define a dict with keys=alphabet and values=complicated characters, and you can make very strong passwords with simple words-sentences.I just wrote it for an example, of course you can add them to dict later, you dont have to write. But basic way is for that is better I think.

Comment: if i were making passwords, that would be sound advice.  as i am cracking passwords, that is inadequate.  i didn't make them, but i know they are the hex numbers which make up the serial number, and it is on a label on a box they come in.  that is also why i know they cannot be too big to handle in a program (a computer assigned them) and it will not take 6000 hard drives to hold them.  all it is is counting, hell, i could put them comma delimited into a big text file.  there's an idea, thanx for making me talk it out.

Answer (score -2):

all of this is well and good, however, none of it accomplishes my purpose.  if python cannot handle such large numbers, i will have to use something else.  as i stated, i do not want to generate random anything, i need a list of sequential hex characters which are anywhere from 12 characters to 20 characters long.  it is to make a dictionary of passwords which are nothing more than a hex number that should be about 16 characters long.

does anyone have any suggestions on what i can use for this purpose?  i think some type of c language should do the trick, but i know less about c or c++ than python.  sounds like this will take a while, but that's ok, it is just a research project.

i have come up with another possibility, counting in hex starting from 11 f's and going until i reach 20 f's.  this would produce about 4.3 billion numbes, which should fit in a 79 million page word document.  sounds like it is a little large, but if i go from 14 f's to 18 f's, that should be manageable.  here is the code i am proposing now:

```
x = 0xffffffffffffff
def gen_pwd(x):
    while x <= 0xffffffffffffffffff:
        return x
        string = str(x)
    f = open("root/Home/sdnlnk_pwd.txt")    
    print f.upper(string, 'a')
    f.write(string)
    x = x + 0x1
gen_pwd()
```