# Creating a comma delimited list in python

Tags: python, hex

I have a need for a list of numbers, they need to be hex numbers. The list needs to be separated by commas (or anything really, just as long as they are separate) so that I can use the list as input to another program.

I want to start at 0xffffffffff and go to 0xffffffffffffffffffff, printing each number to a text file, then a comma (separator), and then the next number, etc. The code I have currently counts, creates a file, and inputs the numbers.

Tthe problem is it is decimal notation, not hex and it has no seperators.  here is what i have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#count in hex from 10 f's to 20 f's and write to comma 
#delimited file to create a dictionary

def count_hex():
    x = 0xffffffffff
    while x <= 0xffffffffffffffffffff:
       x += 0x1
        s = str(x)
        s.upper()
        with open("dictionary.txt", "a") as diction:
            diction.write(s)

count_hex()
```

I have played around with it by putting in separators, and even found a place that said i had to use import CSV, but that is something that I do not understand and would have to change everything.

It seems that since it is mostly working, a few tweaks would be better than rewriting something that I do not understand.

Comment: Those are going to be _a lot_ of numbers in that file... "a lot" as in _10^24_. Is your hard drive big enough for such a file?

Comment: "A list separated by comma's": do you mean a string (containg hex numbers)? A list contains elements, there is no special separator.

Comment: For convenience, there's also the `hex()` function: e.g., `hex(5)` gives the string `'0x5'`.

Comment: `diction.write(",".join([hex(i).upper() for i in range(0xffffff, 0xffffffffffff)]))` may do what you want; not sure if it's the best idea (and no, I didn't properly count the `f`s).

Comment: @evert: the downside is that your code will form the entire huge sting in memory first.

Comment: @9000 Yup; that's why the "not sure" is there (tobias_k mentions the rough amount of memory needed; I didn't bother with the mental math tbh). But I just like `<str>.join()`. I should've left out the `[]` though.

Comment: @tobias_k: it gets worse! If you write the numbers to file as "0x111111111111\n" (using the fewest possible digits) it will take 2.77 * 10**25 bytes. That is the equivalent of about _eight hundred_ 5-terabyte hard drives _for every person on Earth_.

Comment: it is merely a list of numbers, granted with some big digits, but not that big.  maybe python cannot handle it, but something can.  and no, the range is to big for python, i tried that already.  and how can i upvote anything that didn't help?  can python count from an arbitrary number and keep counting and printing each new number or not?  the numbers came from a computer originally, so i know it can be done, just trying to reverse engineer another way to do it, as i have no access to the original way.  seems to me that it could be made to put a number on a list, then write it, then forget it.

Comment: @sfzombie13: Put another way: if you stored a billion numbers a second, it would take just over 38 million years to go through all of them. Python can do it - but you might not want to wait for it to finish.

Comment: how did a computer assign the numbers i the first place, if it really takes that long to do it?  and with a computer that can run at 3.7 ghz, even though all the processes do not count at the same time, it should not take more than a few weeks to do.  there are only 4 odd billion numbers decimal in there, and storing a billion numbers a second takes about 5 seconds.  i want to start at 12 f's and stop at 20 f's.  that is 8 f's or 4.3 billion numbers decimal.

Comment: @HughBothwell sorry, didn't see your comment while I was composing my answer.  To sfzombi13 You're really off in your computation of how many numbers there are (check my answer).

Comment: @sfzombie13: f's are not additive! In decimal terms, a billion is 1000 *times* a million, not 1000 *more than* a million. In your example, 20 f's is 4.3 billion *times* 281 trillion, not *more than*.

Comment: from ffffffffffff to ffffffffffffffffffff there are ffffffff.  unless my math is wrong.  that converts to 4.3 billion in decimal.  please enlighten me as to how a computer cannot start at 1 and count to 4.3 billion without taking millions of years.  i am telling you that it is impossible for a computer to take 38 million years to count to 4.3 billion.  and it is utterly impossible to use 800 5 terabyte hard drives to store those numbers.  if that were the case, i couldn't type it out, it wouldn't work.  i just want the numbers written to a list and if it takes weeks, so be it.

Comment: I wonder what kind of program might use these numbers as _input_. Isn't it much easier just to keep a running counter in that program? It would be easier to program than reading and parsing a file.

Comment: @sfzombie13 your math is wrong.  Consider a smaller example: from `11` to `11111` is not `111` (ie "3 more ones"), but `11111 - 11 = 11100` (which is _much_ (100x) bigger than `111`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [python code to generate password list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678970/python-code-to-generate-password-list)

Answer (score 2):

First, you reopen the file every time you want to write a number into it. It's slow.
Then, you forget to format the number as hex, and forget to put the actual comma!

```
def writeHex(start, stop, filename):
  with open(filename, "w") as output:
    for number in xrange(start, stop):
      output.write("%x, " % number)  # writes smth like "ffffff,"

writeHex(0xfffff, 0x100000000000000000000000, "dictionary.txt")
```

Note that all the numbers are written in one line, and there's a comma after the last number. Adding "\n" if/where needed and adding a variable like `is_first_number` to avoid the comma placement at the very end are left as an exercise.

Comment: that is very close to what i need, i just need the numbers to be separated by something, like a comma.  i have done some exercises where it prints a list separated by a comma, but i can't make that work with numbers.  i am about to just give up, it has been over a week.  it seems so simple to make a computer count, just hard to make it write it down.

Comment: Read a little bit about string formatting, because you output strings, not [raw] numbers.

Comment: @sfzombie13 There _is_ a comma separator in the format string: `"%x, "`

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem you're going to have is that there are just too many numbers:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0xffffffffffffffffffff
1208925819614629174706175L
>>> 0xffffffffff
1099511627775L
>>> 0xffffffffffffffffffff - 0xffffffffff
1208925819613529663078400L
>>> GB = 1024 ** 3
>>> GB
1073741824
>>> (0xffffffffffffffffffff - 0xffffffffff) / GB
1125899906841600L
>>> TB = 1024 ** 4
>>> (0xffffffffffffffffffff - 0xffffffffff) / TB
1099511627775L
>>>
```

ie. if each number only took 1 byte to store, you would need a very large number of TBs to store the file.

To put it another way: if you can process 100 million numbers per second...

```
>>> (0xffffffffffffffffffff - 0xffffffffff) / (100 * 10**6)
12089258196135296L
>>> _ / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365)
383347862L
>>>
```

it will take 383347862 years to finish.

[edit:] you seem to not appreciate how big `0xffffffffffffffffffff` really is and insist on counting `f`s.  Consider this:

```
>>> for i in range(10, 21):
...     lowf = '0x' + 'f' * i
...     print 'from %22s to 0xffffffffffffffffffff' % lowf,
...     low = int(lowf, 16)
...     print  ((0xffffffffffffffffffff - low) / (100 * 10**6)) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365), 'years'
...
from           0xffffffffff to 0xffffffffffffffffffff 383347862 years
from          0xfffffffffff to 0xffffffffffffffffffff 383347862 years
from         0xffffffffffff to 0xffffffffffffffffffff 383347862 years
from        0xfffffffffffff to 0xffffffffffffffffffff 383347861 years
from       0xffffffffffffff to 0xffffffffffffffffffff 383347839 years
from      0xfffffffffffffff to 0xffffffffffffffffffff 383347497 years
from     0xffffffffffffffff to 0xffffffffffffffffffff 383342013 years
from    0xfffffffffffffffff to 0xffffffffffffffffffff 383254271 years
from   0xffffffffffffffffff to 0xffffffffffffffffffff 381850410 years
from  0xfffffffffffffffffff to 0xffffffffffffffffffff 359388621 years
from 0xffffffffffffffffffff to 0xffffffffffffffffffff 0 years
```

i.e. by only considering 19 `f`s (up from 10) to 20 `f`s you'll be saving 23959241 years of execution time. Those 23 million years drown compared to the 360 million years that are left (again assuming you can process 100 million numbers per second -- which you can't).